# How to add script in content page of c# web form application

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I need to add java script tag in content page of asp.net application. The script works fine with html tags but in content it is not working here is the code.

```
    <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <div class="panel panel-primary" id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="panel panel-heading">Registration</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <label>
                From:
                <asp:TextBox ID="datepicker" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Timer runat="server"></asp:Timer>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>    

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker();
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: What's not working? Please be more specific and explain what you already did to debug your problem. Your code should be a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: textbox with id datepicker is not showing calander

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the namingcontainer of webforms

at runtime the Htmlwriter translates

```
<input type="text" id="ctl00_datepicker" />
```

with this behaviour jquery couldn't find the element as it is checking the complete id field

so wether you add the ClientIdMode="static" to

```
<asp:TextBox ID="datepicker" ClientIdMode="Static"
```

or you call the element with something like this

```
$(function () {
            $("input[name*='datepicker']").datepicker();
        });
```

https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/